ошибка ModuleNotFoundError. не видет мои файлы, не импортирует
Структура проекта

При запуске python3 todo_server.py выдает ошибку:
from gRPC.traning_gRPC.model import Todo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gRPC'

Мой импорт:
from gRPC.traning_gRPC.model import Todo

прописывала путь traning_gRPC.model и просто model. Так же прописывала абсолютный путь, та же ошибка
меняла PYTHONPATH путь не помогло
виртуальная среда в порядке
переустанавливала пай чарм и пробовала использовать пай чарм другого года
Возможно жестко туплю и не вижу очевидного, подскажите где может быть ошибка


Когда вы запускаете код, ваша программа всегда смотрит на какую-то папку. Если запускаете просто python3 todo_server.py в папке server, то в этой папке действительно нет модуля gRPC.
Положите todo_server.py на одном уровне с папкой gRPC, и все заработает.
Или лучше создайте файл main.py, чтобы он вызвал код из todo_server.py.

спасибо. сделала main.py и запустила оттуда todo_server.py все модули дидет)
